# Notifications (other than e-mail) in sharepoint 2013

Tags: email, alert

I want notifications in sharepoint 2013 similar to Facebook notifications (not e-mail).

Is this possible? What other notification methods are available in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like the Globe icon notifications? you don't have that kind of notifications but you will have to build your own. An idea would be to create a Visual Web Part called alerts that are stored in a SharePoint List targeted by user. Extend the Out Of the Box ribbon an build something like this
[image]

That icons are inside UpdatePanels so that the postback don't occur in the entire page.

Tell me if you need more help

Comment: Ya globe kind of notifications.thanks for the idea will try using it

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify, what kind of notification you need. "Like in Facebook" - this would suggest to me some dropdown panel on your masterpage?

Yes, something like this is possible. I have implemented similar functionality, where panel   was added to masterpage and JavaScript is used to query user newsfeed.

[In this blog post](http://www.goleszympansy.eu/2013/07/sharepoint-social-feed-how-to-get.html) I wrote, where to start, and how to retrieve "mentions" and newsfeed, using SharePoint's JavaScript Object Model (JSOM).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.what I want exactly is I have a menu in master page and in that menu i have a tab for notifications and in that notifications i want all my alerts like if someone has raised a question to me I should have all my alerts in that notificationS.

Answer (score -1):

In SP 2013 you have a feature called "My Sites" where you have many features present in social/community sites.
Check newsfeed section in
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382643.aspx

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE Deptor! The question ask specifically for notifications other than e-mail, which I don't see in your answer. Could you elaborate on notifications in your answer, making it easier to understand how you can solve this issue. Thank you.